# thrift async c++ example

Tags: c++, asynchronous, thrift

I've looked in the Apache Thrift distribution, and in the apache.org website, seeking an example, and I was unsuccessful.

I'd like someone to point me at an example implementation of an async client
and a non-blocking server in classic Apache Thrift (not the newer branch from
Facebook), which uses "--gen cpp".

I can see a similar question with title "apache thrift C++ async client" but the answer didn't contain all the pieces.

I'd like to see the ".thrift" file, and then the filled out server, and the corresponding client code.

I really want to believe someone has done this, and I'm just not as good a google-user as I thought I was.

I understand that the Facebook version (fbthrift) is intended to help do this better, but I've been frustrated by how unstable that version seems to be. If anyone can point me to a stable version of fbthrift that's not being modified daily, I could consider that as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by an async client but I will try my best to answer this question based off what I understand.

If by an "async client", you mean to talk about async like in node.js, where execution follows a callback structure, AFAIK that is not a part of the open sourced thrift.  It is however available in [`fbthrift`](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift).  Facebook has a bunch of tools that go in conjunction with [`fbthrift`](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift) including their popular open source C++ library [`folly`](https://github.com/facebook/folly).  Calls to other thrift services via thrift C++ client interfaces must block.

This is the code I used to start off when I was experimenting with the async non blocking server.  Hopefully it helps!

**something.thrift**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/thrift --gen cpp

namespace cpp something

service Something {
  i32 ping()
}
```

**SomethingServer.cpp**

```
#include "gen-cpp/Something.h"
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <thrift/server/TThreadedServer.h>
#include <thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <thrift/concurrency/ThreadManager.h>

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class SomethingHandler : virtual public something::SomethingIf {
public:
    SomethingHandler() {
        cout << "Initialized" << endl;
    }

    int32_t ping() override {
        // Your implementation goes here
        cout << "Ping!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace ::apache::thrift;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::concurrency;
    using boost::shared_ptr;
    using namespace ::something;

    int port = 9090;
    shared_ptr<SomethingHandler> handler(new SomethingHandler());
    shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new SomethingProcessor(handler));
    shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

    // using thread pool with maximum 15 threads to handle incoming requests
    shared_ptr<ThreadManager> threadManager
        = ThreadManager::newSimpleThreadManager(15);
    shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory> threadFactory
        = shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory>(new PosixThreadFactory());
    threadManager->threadFactory(threadFactory);
    threadManager->start();

    TNonblockingServer server(processor, protocolFactory, port, threadManager);
    server.serve();

    return 0;
}
```

**SomethingClient.cpp**

```
#include "Something.h"

#include <thrift/transport/TSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

using namespace Test;

int main(int /* argc */, char** /* argv */) {
  boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
  boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TFramedTransport(socket));
  boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

  SomethingClient client(protocol);
  transport->open();
  for (auto i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
      client.ping();
  }
  transport->close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm delighted to see this code.  This is exactly the sort of example I was looking for, in that it appears to not come from "fbthrift", and it doesn't depend on packages (like "folly") that we were hoping to avoid.

I'll be giving this example a try later this evening, but I wanted to take the time to thank you now!

More information later...

Comment: Upon further reading, it appears that your sample code does not implement any sort of callback.  

I think you're trying to tell me that I literally MUST use fbthrift to successfully create a client call that returns immediately, in conjunction with a callback mechanism when the server is done with its task.  

Is that your understanding?

Comment: @GordonFossum yes, that's what i make from it and the issues I've seen open for thrift. fbthrift uses folly futures with callback support to enable callback based handling. Boost futures do have that but I don't think anyone has implemented that in the open sourced thrift yet.